# Kubernetes leaves a lot of resources on Google Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) to set up an k8s ingress with a gcloud load balancer.

After creating a service and ingress in my cluster and deleting them  I noticed that I run out of resources in the gcloud free trial quota.

Every time I create an ingress, k8s also creates a [Backend Service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service) and some other resources (Forwarding rules, Health checks, IP addresses, ...). But after I delete the k8s service and ingress this resources never get deleted.

Do I need to delete them manually or is there also a way to set up releasing of these resources?

Comment: They should be deleted (At least 1.3.x was deleting the resources, however there was a change discussion going on on automatic release of the resources (unhandy if you want to have fixed ips)). Check the kubernetes logs to see if there is a remark in there regarding not executing the expected steps, and check the interface definition to see if you have to add additional flags in your kube version

Comment: Thanks @NorbertvanNobelen for the replay. I tried it now multiple times and they actually got deleted. I can't reproduce it now. Maybe the order I delete them in affects it. I will experiment with it.

Comment: Gcloud is not bug free. You might be hit by one of their bugs.

Comment: I just followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) and it worked for me.  I did not go through the optional steps (5 and 6). The backend services  and the whole LB got deleted after I ran “kubectl delete ingress basic-ingress”

Comment: As NorbertvanNobelen said, I think it was a bug. If I created and immediately tried to delete the resources afterwards, some didn't get removed.